# How to use SNAPSHOT of ncelab?

Tags: cadence

Now I'm trying to use the function of snapshot of ncelab of cadence.
I found some special function about SNAPSHOT, so I tried so much with this. but I can't use the SNAPSHOT.

So Would you let me know what about the usages of SNAPSHOT of ncelab of cadence?

my verilog code is like as below.

```
module top();

reg a;
reg b;
wire c;

assign c = a+b;


endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Cadence snapshot is more about saving the current state of the simulator and later on reusing the same state for resuming the simulation. It is used for the long run simulations to avoid issues with the tool crash/server issues.

Snapshot is more like a checkpoint where you save a state and if something breaks later on, you can resume from this checkpoint instead of restarting backc from 0.

On a side note, you can not change source code/compilation library etc. while doing the resume operation.